# Android ListView with toast message problems

Tags: c#, android, listview

i have the next problem, i have an Activity1 : Activity,
with the following code:

```
private string[] items;
    public ListView lv;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        ListView lv = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);
          items = new string[] { "Aaaa", "bbb", "cccc", "dddd",    "eeee", "ffff", "gggg" };
        var ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, items);
        lv.Adapter = ListAdapter;


    }



    protected void OnListClick(ListView listView, View view, int pos, long id)
    {
        var t = items[pos];
        Android.Widget.Toast.MakeText(this, t, Android.Widget.ToastLength.Short).Show();


    }
}
```

The problem is as follows, when i debug the app, and click on a row, no toast message appears, nothing...... some help pls.....

the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
p1:orientation="horizontal"
p1:minWidth="25px"
p1:minHeight="25px"
p1:layout_width="fill_parent"
p1:layout_height="fill_parent"
p1:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
<LinearLayout
    p1:id="@+id/layoutCalendar"
    p1:orientation="horizontal"
    p1:layout_width="200.0dp"
    p1:layout_height="fill_parent"
    p1:layout_gravity="right"
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px">
    <ListView
        p1:minWidth="25px"
        p1:minHeight="25px"
        p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
        p1:layout_height="fill_parent"
        p1:id="@+id/listView1" />
   </LinearLayout>
   <calendarcontrol.CalendarMonthView
    p1:id="@+id/calendarView2"
    p1:clickable="true"
    p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    p1:layout_gravity="right" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use onItemSelectListener instead of onClick

```
 public class AppActivity extends Activity {    

            public Activity activity;


            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.main);
                    activity = this;
                    ListView lv = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);
                    items = new string[] { "Aaaa", "bbb", "cccc", "dddd",    "eeee", "ffff", "gggg" };
                    var ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, items);

                    lv.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {  
                         public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View childView, int position, long id) {  
                              var t = items[position];
                              Android.Widget.Toast.MakeText(activity, t, Android.Widget.ToastLength.Short).Show();
                               }
                        }); 
                    lv.Adapter = ListAdapter;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi KEYSAN, i cannot use setOnItemSelectedListener, i only have setonclicklistener ,because i have an Activity class not a list Activity class.I think that's the reason why i cannot use  setOnItemSelectedListener,because i get the "does not contain a definition for "setOnItemSelectedListener"" when i build it.

Comment: do not define like "protected void OnListClick(ListView listView, View view, int pos, long id) "  
add this code before lv.Adapter = ListAdapter; (don't forget to change lv to listview :D )

Comment: Can you please be a little more specific, i dont quite understand what i should do. Sorry and Thank you!