# ListView Group Position set Intent - Android

Tags: android, listview

I have ListView with 6 items, when I click the items I want to go to different activity using intent. I put intent but it goes to only one activity. I want to set intent in different group position. here is my code.

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));

    selection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selection);
}

public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position,long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(parent, v, position, id);

    selection.setText(items[position]);
    Intent hash=new Intent(ListUpdatesActivity.this,Activity2.class);
    startActivity(hash);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be use onItemSelected instead of onClick.
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17995749/1752867) are an example about your question.

Define your activity like that. And do not use onClick.
add the following lines to onItemSelectedListener;

```
selection.setText(items[position]);
Intent hash=new Intent(ListUpdatesActivity.this,Activity2.class);
startActivity(hash);
```

Comment: Should I put it like this selection.setText(items[1]);

Comment: i mean u can put in the OnItemSelectedLister what u want. It's just an example. define a global veriable items[] and access items like  items[position]